# Post request in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-networking

I'm trying to do a POST request from Unity3D to my web server. Everything works correctly in editor, but when I build the binaries and try to do the same from them - it doesn't look like it reaches server.

On server I process them as:

```
if(isset($_POST['name']) || isset($_POST['score']))
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $score = $_POST['score'];
    ....
}
```

And in Unity/C# I do this:

```
IEnumerator Upload()
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("name", name.text.Replace("|", " ").ToString());
    form.AddField("score", (int)(highScore));
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("https://server_name.com/page.php", form);
    yield return www.Send();
}
```

Is there any reason why this should work in editor and shouldn't work while running built binaries?

Thanks!

EDIT: As per request - my binaries were built for Windows and Linux, and both have the same error. I'm running editor on Windows (same machine as on which I used Windows binary) - and I don't have any problem in editor.

Comment: Try to return a value from the php then attempt to read it in Unity and check if there is an error. At the-same time, it would be nice to mention which platform you are building and trying this on.

Comment: Right, so I built this for Linux and Windows - the problem is present on both. I'm running editor on Windows machine (and the same code works from there).

Comment: Ok. Do what I said above. Run it in Editor and make sure you receive the value sent from php with `UnityWebRequest.downloadHandler.text`. Now, build it and see if you can receive the-same value. Also check the `UnityWebRequest.error` to see if there is any error.

Comment: Ended up with no error in editor - and received the value.

Comment: And I believe I've found a problem - right after I call upload, I load next scene (without waiting for Coroutine to finish) - which might be the root of the problem.

Comment: Or (for test purposes) just don't change the scene, and see what is the result of the request. If you change the scene the associated MonoBehaviours will be destroyed, and the running coroutines will stop.

Answer (score 1):

I don't even understand how this is working inside the editor...

You are not following the way described in the doc :

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm.html

You don't have to use UnityWebRequest at all: only WWW and WWWForm.

Try this :

```
IEnumerator Upload () {
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("name", name.text.Replace("|", " ").ToString());
    form.AddField("score", (int)(highScore));

    WWW result = new WWW("https://server_name.com/page.php", form );

    yield return result;

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.error)) {
        print( "Error : " + result.error );
    } else {
        Debug.Log(result.text);
    }
}
```

**Edit :**

Ok my bad, your example is on the doc. I wasn't aware that WWW was evolving (Nice communication unity...).

So here it my advice : Keep using legacy WWW. It's working perfectly fine.

Because this is classic unity : When they say a new feature is out, it's broken.